# Terminal output not what Logic Analyzer gets

Tags: c, hex, spi

This should be easy, but it's got me stumped. I have a physical board I'm programming in C to read information from another chip via SPI. When I probe the correct pins, I receive the following codeword:

0xD54, except it fluctuates a bit around that. That's fine, because its giving me a digital representation on an analog signal. The value 0xD54 is more or less the correct value. It is definitely in the right range.

The terminal output for my program is giving me values like 0xAA8. Definitely not in the same range.
Here is the code:

```
uint32_t i;
uint8_t uc_pcs;
static uint16_t data;

uint16_t *p_buffer;

p_buffer = p_buf;

for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    spi_write(SPI_MASTER_BASE, p_buffer[i], 0, 0);
    /* Wait transfer done. */
    while ((spi_read_status(SPI_MASTER_BASE) & SPI_SR_RDRF) == 0);
    spi_read(SPI_MASTER_BASE, &data, &uc_pcs);

    p_buffer[i] = data;
    printf("Data = %X\n\r", *(p_buffer + i));
}
```

Here's some raw data. The data on the left is the correct data from probing the board. The data on the right is what was received in the terminal through the above code.

```
D51    AA2
D4F    A9E
D52    AA4
D52    AA4
```

Answer (score 0):

As per usual, I figure out my problem after making a question for it. I guess writing things out really helps. Normally I'd delete the post, but I found the solution slightly humorous and perhaps entertaining.

Comparing D51 to AA2, I noticed that...AA2 is simply D51 shifted left. What? Why is my data *shifted left*? I never did that in my code. So, I shifted it back the other way to compensate and got the right values.

That's when I realized it. The clock polarity setting I had was backwards. It was only reading 11 of the 12 bits, so i was reading everything, but off on the order of magnitude.